# How do I hide an iframe when browser is offline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe that goes to a website but I want to make it so it gets hidden if the site cannot be reached.

If you can, please use `http://weather.gc.ca/wxlink/wxlink.html?cityCode=on-143&amp;lang=e` to make it easier to demonstrate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "the browser is offline" and "the site cannot be reached" are different things. Which one do you actually care about?

Comment: I guess `onerror` will handle both cases, user not online and site not reachable

Comment: @A.Wolff — I don't think `onerror` works cross-origin, which this is.

Comment: @Quentin Ya even onload works, looks like onerror doesn't

Comment: Is anyone going to post a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding site offline, you could use this workaround i guess:

```
$('<img/>', {
    id: "_tmpIMG",
    src: "http://weather.gc.ca/weathericons/00.gif"
}).hide().on({
    load: siteOnline,
    error: siteNotOnline
}).appendTo('body');

function siteNotOnline(){ 
    alert('site not online');
    $('#_tmpIMG').remove();
    $('#iframe').hide();
}

function siteOnline(){ 
    alert('site online');
    $('#_tmpIMG').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You add this

```
<iframe src='' frameborder='0' width="800" height="600" onError="location.href='offline.jpg'"></iframe>

<img src="yourpath/onlinetestimg.jpg" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden" onError="document.getElementById('iframe').innerHTML = '<img src=\'offline.jpg\'>'">
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you won't get an error event for a cross-origin resource that fails to load. If I give a URL that triggers a DNS error (for example) the error event does not fire.

Comment: It would be a security problem since you could use it (for example) to determine if someone was logged into a website that gave Not Authorised errors if they were not logged in.